# Java graphics not drawing getX() and getY() from player class

Tags: java, swing

Well there's not much I can say but basically I have a `Player` class and then in the `GFX` class I am drawing the `Player` with his `getX()` and `getY()` so `player.getX()`

So as you can see I made the getters and setters but now it won't draw in `GFX` it just gives me errors.

```
    package com.shiny21.players;

public class PlayerR {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;

    public PlayerR(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setX(10);
        setY(10);

    }

    public void init(){

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }



}

package com.shiny21.graphics;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import com.shiny21.players.PlayerR;

public class GFX extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    PlayerR red;

    public GFX(){

        PlayerR red = new PlayerR(getX(), getY());

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocus();

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / 60, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void step(){
        System.out.println(":p");
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 4, 4);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(red.getX(), red.getY(), 4, 4);


    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        step();
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are thrown?

Comment: You're declaring `PlayerR red` twice, remove `PlayerR` from the second use

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll edit the answer once you post the error logs. For now I'll point out a thing or two:

---

```
public PlayerR(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    setX(10);
    setY(10);

}
```

Why are you directly assigning the variable and then using it's respective setter method? It should just be:

```
public PlayerR(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

---

Also:

```
 PlayerR red = new PlayerR(getX(), getY());
```

Should be `red = new PlayerR(getX(), getY());`

As `PlayerR red;` is globally declared already.